# Google maps v3 issues with IE7 and IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here's the site to test:

http://5.foodtrucksmap.appspot.com/la/

I've tried about every method to debug IE that's documented on the internet.  None of my efforts have made the problem clear to me.  What I know is that the map is being loaded, but it isn't being displayed property.  I can get it to display by using firebug to giving #map_canvas (this is the DOM element which is given to the maps constructor) the properties `width:100%; height:100%; position: absolute !important;`  The important is necessary because otherwise maps will add position:relative for some reason, which will then make the entire map invisible even though it exists in the DOM.

Even with these 'fixes', the result is ludicrous.  The actual map ends up being a tiny square in the top left corner of the map which is always changing in size, even though the map panel is clearly where it should be because the remaining background is gray and the google logo is in the bottom left corner.  I'm really at a loss for what to do next.

Thank you for any help you may be able to provide.

EDIT:  Here's [what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiWrw.png)

Comment: var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(33.461234,-118.718262),new google.maps.LatLng(34.273106,-117.550964));   <- is that line correct? Setting 2 bounds on the same line?

Comment: yea, the bounds need a bottom left and top right latlng.

Comment: I was getting 'Operation aborted' error in IE7, so I read up on that: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927917  And you do have script tags within elements (not to mention sheer number of external js files). So maybe you can try moving those scripts to right above closing body tag. Have no idea if that's gonna help, but maybe worth a try.

Comment: @AR it seems to not like showads.js, the google script that loads the adsense ads.  Ive used this same code plenty of times and had it work in IE named (for one example, check out the live site at http://www.foodtrucksmap.com/la/ )  I wonder why it doesnt like it in this case.

Comment: @AR I believe i just fixed that error by using window.onload instread of jquery ready.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if you've since solved this, but there doesn't seem to be an issue on my copy of IE (IE8)

[image: http://imgur.com/5VOQ9]

Comment: Hmmm, interesting.  I can't get it to work on XP/IE8, Vista IE7, or Win 7/IE9.  What OS are you running?